# All possible ways to display HTTP image on my HTTPS website

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, ssl, https

I need to load and display HTTP images from an external website, in my HTTPS website.
Seems like all previous answers are not relevant anymore. Are we still able to achieve this goal? is there any workaround?

Comment: I have no idea which answers you refer to with *"... all previous answers are not relevant anymore"*. At least the one I've used to close the question is still relevant and basically the only choice: make them use HTTPS or proxy their HTTP-only content on your server so that it gets served with HTTPS.

Comment: It may be worth noting that in a soon to be released version of Chrome Browser they are going to ban mixed content, so an HTTPS website will not be allowed to display anything via HTTP:80. You should probably be aware of this.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue, using a [free image proxy service](https://images.weserv.nl) so the final url becomes `https://images.weserv.nl/?url=http://site/image.jpg`